# Qual é a origem de “dedetizar”?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Qual é a origem da palavra *dedetizar* (aplicação de venenos para controles de pragas)?

Essa palavra também existe em Portugal? Se não, como é chamado o procedimento?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Dedetizar*** tem origem em ***DDT***, que é a sigla pela qual é internacionalmente conhecido o [*diclorodifeniltricloroetano* (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDT), um pesticida muito usado no século passado. Inicialmente *dedetizar* significava, como o nome indica, aplicar *DDT*, mas atualmente vale também para outros insecticidas [(Aulete digital)](http://www.aulete.com.br/dedetizar). Até porque desde 2009 que o *DDT* está banido no Brasil. Muitos outros países já o tinham banido antes, devido a efeitos altamente nocivos no meio ambiente e saúde humana. Atualmente só é produzido na Índia [(Wikipedia em inglês).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDT)

Segundo o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), a sigla *DDT* é de origem inglesa, e o [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ddt) data-a de 1943. Não demorou mais de cinco anos para a palavra *dedetização* surgir no Brasil, como mostra esta [*Mensagem Apresentada ao Congresso Nacional* de 1948:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=S1MLAQAAIAAJ&q=dedetiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o&dq=dedetiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8m6Pt963PAhWCnRoKHadxDks4ZBDoAQibATAS)

> Entre as principais realizações, levadas a efeito nêste setor, em 1947, devem ser incluídos: […] e duas grandes campanhas de **dedetização** e de proteção às populações da Bacia do São Francisco e da Baixada Fluminense (p. 62)
>
> Como prosseguimento do programa, — que já vem dando resultados tão auspiciosos nas duas zonas malarígenas mencionadas, — está prevista a **dedetização**, em ciclos sucessivos, de várias outra regiões […] (p. 63)

A palavra está também na [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/dedetizar) e no [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dedetizar), que não a restringem ao Brasil, mas eu nunca a tinha ouvido em Portugal. Também não vem no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa.

O termo usado para controle de pragas em Portugal pode ser [***desinfestação***](http://www.aulete.com.br/desinfesta%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ou, para pragas específicas, [***desratização***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/desratiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ou ***desbaratização***. Curiosamente não encontro esta palavra em dicionário nenhum. Mas basta [googlar *desbaratização*](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=desbaratiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para se encontrar imensos resultados em Portugal, nomeadamente empresas que oferecem o serviço.

Comment: Achei muito interessante, aqui no Brasil atribuirmos essa prática de "dedetização" por conta de um composto químico usado...

Comment: Já ouvi falar de desratização e atualmente está surgindo o termo "desinsetização", mas não tão popular aqui... Agora desbaratização, é bem novo para mim, vi no google o serviço: aqui é parte do serviço de dedetização

Comment: Desbaratização é novo para mim também.

Comment: *Desbaratização* aqui é bastante frequente. Fiquei admirado por não a encontrar nos dicionários. A barata é das pragas urbanas mais comuns em Portugal.

Comment: Muito interessante, nunca tinha pensado nisto dessa forma, mas tem toda a lógica.

Comment: @JorgeB. Estás a falar da *desbaratização?* Eu quando vejo qualquer estabelecimento "fechado para desbaratização" presumo sempre que o principal ou único problema são baratas.

Comment: @Jacinto estou a falar da dedetização. De qualquer forma aqui em Braga não se usa muito desbaratização e sim desinfestação.

Comment: @JorgeB. Já conhecias *dedetização?*. Eu nunca tinha ouvido.

Comment: @Jacinto já conhecia sim, mas não me perguntes como...

Comment: @JorgeB. Eh pá! era mesmo isso que eu te ia perguntar :)

Comment: ahahahahahahahahaha

Comment: Dedetização é tão comum no Brasil que tinha nas páginas amarelas (lista telefônica) um seção dedicada a esses serviços

Comment: Tenho aqui umas páginas amarelas de 2012 (as últimas distribuídas) e aparece a categoria *desinfeção e desinfestação*.